# Why I got error You do not have sufficient permissions to access the inventory?

Tags: oracle

I need to install oracle database on oracle linux
when I run command

`./runInstaller` on oracle user I got the following error :

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access the inventory '/u01/app/oraInventory'. Installation cannot continue. It is required that the primary group of the install user is same as the inventory owner group. Make sure that the install user is part of the inventory owner group and restart the installer.
```

How to solve this error and continue installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you what the problem is and how to solve it:

`You do not have sufficient permissions to access the inventory '/u01/app/oraInventory'. Installation cannot continue. It is required that the primary group of the install user is same as the inventory owner group. Make sure that the install user is part of the inventory owner group and restart the installer.`

So first check the primary group of the install user. Login as  user that does the installation ad execute the `id` command. In my environment I install with the `oracle`user, so I login with the `oracle`user and get

```
$ id
uid=1001(oracle) gid=1000(oinstall) groups=202(dba)
```

So the user is `oracle` and the primary group is `oinstall`.

Next check the directory of the inventory:

```
$ ls -ld /u01/app/oraInventory
drwxrwx--- 7 oracle oinstall 4096 Jan 16 12:34 /u01/app/oraInventory
```

This show that the owner of the directory is `oracle` and the group of the directory is `oinstall`, so this is as required in the error message. The privileges of the owner is `rwx` and the privileges of the group are `rxw`. The user and group members are allowed to read, write and change to the directory. So everything is fine on my system.

With

```
ls -lR /u01/app/oraInventory
```

you can check all files in the directory´and its subdirectories. The output should be similar to the following. User is the same as the owner of the  directory `/u01/app/oraInventory`, and file type and permission starts always with `drwxrwx` or `-rw-rw-`, e.g.

```
$ ls -lR /u01/app/oraInventory
/u01/app/oraInventory:
total 44
drwxrwx---  2 oracle oinstall  4096 Jun 26  2021 Contents
drwxrwx---  2 oracle oinstall  4096 Jun 26  2020 ContentsXML
-rw-rw----  1 oracle oinstall    37 Jun 26  2021 install.platform
...
```

Answer (score 1):

check the group owner of oracle folder and oraInventory folder if it is different you can change it by using this command it should be same :

```
chown -R  oracle:oinstall /u01/app/
chown -R  oracle:oinstall /u01/app/oraInventory
```